# Problema em implementação de Arvore Binaria

Tags: c++

Boa noite, pessoal. Estou tentando fazer a implementação de uma arvore binaria com metodos para inserir(insert,insertLeft e insertRight) e imprimir
(print).

Tudo vai bem ate eu tentar inserir um nó na arvore atraves do metodo insert,
eu consigo criar o no e atribuir um valor a variavel value dele, porem ao tentar imprimir a arvore nada aparece, o ponteiro root acaba sempre apontando para NULL.

Agradeço desde já

Segue o codigo:

```
class NodeTree {

public:

   int value;
   NodeTree * left;
   NodeTree * right;

   NodeTree() {
     value = 0;
   }

};
```

---

```
#include "NodeTree.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BinaryTree {

public:

NodeTree * root;


BinaryTree() {
    root = NULL;
}



bool isEmpty() {
    return root == NULL;
}


void makeEmpty() {
    root = NULL;
}


void insert(int opcao,int num) {

    NodeTree * node = new NodeTree;
    node->value = num;

    if (opcao == 1) {
        insertRigth(node,root);
    }

    if (opcao == 2) {
        insertLeft(node,root);
    }

}

void insertRigth(NodeTree * node1,NodeTree * root1) {

    if (root1 == NULL) {
        node1->right = NULL;
        node1->left = NULL;
        root1 = node1;
    }
    else {
        insertRigth(node1,root1->right);
    }

}


void insertLeft(NodeTree * node1,NodeTree * root1) {

    if (root1 == NULL) {
        node1->right = NULL;
        node1->left = NULL;
        root1 = node1;
    }
    else {
        insertLeft(node1,root1->left);
    }

}

void print(NodeTree * obj) {

    if (obj == NULL) {
        cout << "A arvore esta vazia, nao e possivel imprimir\n";
        return;
    }

    print(obj->left);

    cout << obj->value << endl;

    print(obj->right);

  }

};
```

---

```
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

BinaryTree arvore;
int sentinela = 0;
int opcao;
int numero;

while (sentinela != 3) {

    system("cls");
    cout << "Opcoes da Arvore Binaria:\n\n1-Inserir\n2-Exibir em Ordem\n3-Sair\n\nOpcao desejada:";
    cin >> sentinela;

    if (sentinela == 1) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Deseja inserir o elemento em qual lado ? 1-Direita / 2-Esquerda: ";
        cin >> opcao;
        cout << "Digite um numero:";
        cin >> numero;
        arvore.insert(opcao, numero);
    }


    if (sentinela == 2) {
        system("cls");
        arvore.print(arvore.root);
        system("PAUSE");
    }

}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> eu consigo criar o no e atribuir um valor a variavel value dele, porem ao tentar imprimir a arvore nada aparece, o ponteiro root acaba sempre apontando para NULL.

O problema é que essa parte da função:

```
root1 = node1;
```

Não altera pra onde `root` está apontando. Pra conseguir fazer isso, você pode 1) passar o endereço do `root`:

```
void insertRigth(NodeTree *node1, NodeTree **root1)
{
    if (*root1 == NULL)
    {
        node1->right = NULL;
        node1->left = NULL;
        *root1 = node1;
    }
    else
    {
        insertRigth(node1, &(*root1)->right);
    }
}
```

Ou 2) receber o `root1` como referência (pois assim você conseguirá alterar o endereço do ponteiro original), não precisando mudar o corpo da função antiga, apenas o protótipo da função:

```
// Corpo continua igual.
void insertRigth(NodeTree *node1, NodeTree *&root1)
```

Comment: Muito obg pela ajuda Mário ! Utilizei a segunda opcao que voce passou e deu certo !